# Bounded Queue in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack, queue

What if I wanted to create a queue with a bound, but I want to create the bound for the queue inside of a function instead of using Class BoundedQueue.Queue(maxsize = 4)? (For information about maximum bound queue: http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html)

Any suggestions?

Here is my code; `capacity` is the maximum bound.

```
class BoundedQueue: 
    # Constructor, which creates a new empty queue, with user-specified capacity:
    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.items = []
        assert(capacity >= 0), "not positive"

        try:
            capacity = int(capacity)
        except TypeError as inst:
            print("Error", inst.args)
        except:
            print("error")
        else:
            itemmax = capacity
```

Comment: What's your question exactly? not sure I follow

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual question is here. By "create the bound for the queue inside of a function," do you mean that the capacity will be a variable rather than a literal value? There's no reason why the standard `Class BoundedQueue.Queue(maxsize = capacity)` shouldn't work here.

Comment: [deque](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) can be bounded by maxlen - will it suffice ?

Comment: I meant that instead of using Class BoundedQueue.Queue(maxsize = capacity). I want the user to input "capacity" so that would be the maximum length of the queue. So, I want the option of having a maximum bound queue created inside the __init__ function

Comment: So you want `capacity` to be a string that, prior to initialization, will be given by the user? Why wouldn't you just convert the string to an int **before** passing it to the `Queue` initializer?

Comment: In short, I still don't understand what the difference in functionality (if any) will be between your queue and `BoundedQueue.Queue`.

Comment: Its a practice question for a class. Thats how we were told to do it. They want us to be creative. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whether you create your own `BoundedQueue` class or subclass an existing one, the thing you seem to be missing is that you will need store the maximum size in the class's `__init__()` (i.e. `self._maxsize = capacity`) and then use it in any of the Queue's other methods which add elements to prevent that number of them from being exceeded.

In order to do that, you'll also need to keep track of how many things are in it as they are added and removed, which means you'll probably also need a `self._cursize` attribute for that value which should also be initialized in the constructor. If you're subclassing a base class, it may already keep track of that for you, so you could just use that instead.

There's some examples of (unbounded) queue implementations in the "Q: What other major types are missing from Python?" section of Peter Norvig's [The Python IAQ: Infrequently Answered Questions](http://norvig.com/python-iaq.html) website which you might find useful if you decide to create your own class.